# BigDecimal.add() being ignored

Tags: java, bigdecimal, currency

I have code like this

```
BigDecimal withoutTax, tax, withTax, totalPrice;
totalPrice = new BigDecimal(0.0);
BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 3)).replace(",", "."));
BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 4)).replace(",", "."));
withoutTax = amount.multiply(price, new MathContext(5));
table.setValueAt(withoutTax.toPlainString(), table.getSelectedRow(), 5);
tax = withoutTax.multiply(new BigDecimal(0.23), new MathContext(2));
table.setValueAt(tax.toPlainString(), table.getSelectedRow(), 7);
withTax = withoutTax.add(tax, new MathContext(5));
table.setValueAt(withTax.toPlainString(), table.getSelectedRow(), 8);
totalPrice.add(withTax, new MathContext(5));
paymentNum.setText(String.valueOf(totalPrice.toPlainString()));
```

why am I receiving that `totalPrice.add` is ignored while `withoutTax.add` is working properly?

Comment: You are assigning the result of `withoutTax.add` and ignoring the result of `totalPrice.add`. If you don't want to ignore the result, assign it to a variable as you did for `withoutTax.add`

Comment: *FYI:* Use of `BigDecimal(double val)` is discouraged. See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29) for why. --- Specifying `new MathContext(5)` on the `add()` calls are unnecessary.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That's answered by looking at [the docs for `BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add-java.math.BigDecimal-)

> **Returns** a BigDecimal whose value is (this + augend), and whose scale is max(this.scale(), augend.scale()).

Emphasis mine. So `add` doesn't modify the existing `BigDecimal` - it can't, since `BigDecimal`s are immutable. [According to the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), `BigDecimal`s are

> **Immutable**, arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers.

Instead of modifying its value, it returns a new value which is equal to the result of the addition.

Change this:

```
totalPrice.add(withTax, new MathContext(5));
```

to this:

```
totalPrice = totalPrice.add(withTax, new MathContext(5));
```

to assign that new value back to the same variable, and it will correctly update like you expect.

Compare that to this line:

```
withTax = withoutTax.add(tax, new MathContext(5));
```

You wouldn't expect the value of `withoutTax` to change simply because you used it in a calculation. In order for that line to work as expected, the `add` method cannot be allowed to modify the object it is called on.

Comment: Thanks, just started with this java money thing

Answer (score 4):

Because you are not assigning it, `BigDecimal` is immutable and the added result will be a newly created `BigDecimal` object which you ignoring.

```
totalPrice = totalPrice.add(withTax, new MathContext(5));
```